# Powerapps - Default value of dropdown with data source

Tags: powerapps

I have a dropdown menu with excel items from one drive. I want to set the value "Please select a value..." as default but I couldn't find the right syntax.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few things to consider:**

1. As long as the string you are typing is in the column tied to the dropdown, you should be able to just type it in ("Please select a value...") as `Default`; no need for the `Lookup()`
2. There is a small typo in the word `Please`
3. If you want to use a `Lookup()` for other reasons, it requires 3 arguments (you currently have 2). Datasource, lookup column and value, return column.

**Try:**

```
Lookup(ServiceInfo, 
    Lokasyon = "Please select a value...", 
    Servis
)
```